# Leverage browser caching not working using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, caching, browser, pagespeed

I am trying to add browser caching in my .htaccess to boost my google page speed score (currently at 86) however its not working. I have used 2 different types and both keep failing the google page speed results.

It was working on our old site (build on laravel php) however just not the new one which is just HTML/CSS/JS

I have used the following:

```
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|png|svg|ico|js|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

and also

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c> 
ExpiresActive on 
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month" 
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month" 
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access 1 month" 
ExpiresByType text/plain "access 1 month" 
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year" 
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year" 
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year" 
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 year" 
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 year" 
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month" 
</IfModule> 
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

and both keep failing. I have placed it at the very top.

I have looked at other responses from here before posting this and still couldn't get it to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks

David

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

```
ExpiresByType image/* A31536000
```

And try adding backslashes and a question mark:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|swf|mp3|vtt|)(\.gz)?$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks for the reply

Will give it a go tomorrow when at work and will update - thanks again